# Figure placement in PDF with R markdown

Tags: pdf, knitr, gtsummary

There's a high likelihood this was asked and answered somewhere else, but I can't seem to find it.

**The Problem**

When I knit to a PDF, my tbl_summary object shows up nowhere near where I would like it.  At first it showed up not only above the code chunk it was in, but above the graph from above that chunk!
I fixed that, but now its a solid page of blank space below where it should be.

**What I've tried**

[Because of notes from here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/figure-placement.html) I've added this code in the beginning of the document:

[image]

I've also tried "extra_dependencies: ["float"] and I've also previously put this code in the first chunk in my document (not there now):

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.pos = "!H", out.extra = "")
```

Right now the relevant tbl_summary object that is showing up a page and half too low (preceded by blank space) is in this code chunk:

[image]

And I've tried it with and without the /newpage before it, and with and without the "fig.cap='Test', fig.pos='h'"

Any help would be appreciated!   Even if its to simply point me towards where this has been previously asked.

Comment: Are you printing with the gt package? It could be that gt doesn't fully support PDF output yet. Perhaps try as_hux_table()?

Comment: I had been using as_gt() and that actually lands in the correct place, but I couldn't seem to figure out how to shrink the font (it spills off the page like crazy), so right now its: as_kable_extra(booktabs = TRUE) %>% kableExtra::kable_styling(font_size = 4)

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg  Is there a way to reduce the font size with hux table or as_gt()?

Comment: Yes, there are functions for font size in both packages. I'm away from a computer for the next few days and I don't have  them memorized.